# Gwan mono : calls to Gwan c# API dump core

Tags: c#, api, mono, g-wan

I'm investigating gwan and am trying to run c# samples with mono, but encountered some problems.

hello.cs dumps core as soon as c# Gwan API (wrapped) is hit. Samples with mono work ok unless Gwan API is called. If You take loan.cs sample it writes output to stdout (console on server) and Gwan calls are commented out:

- line 74

  //lupus commented: Gwan.xbufCat(Gwan.getReply(args[0]), reply.ToString());
- line 237

  //Gwan.xbufCat(Gwan.getReply(args[0]), reply.ToString());

Am I missing something?
Is there something more to do to config c# Gwan API?

Thanks

Mel

Answer (score 0):

Your Linux distribution or Mono release probably made this happen (Linux distributions use different by-default configuration options and consecutive Mono releases are not always compatible with each-other).

On Ubuntu 10.10 and Ubuntu 12.04 (both 64-bit) the following Mono release works great:

`mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.2 (tarball Wed Dec 26 11:43:57 CET 2012)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)`

Since you disclose nothing about your OS nor about the Mono runtime you are using, telling what works for us is the maximum that can be done.

The `loan.cs` comments were added by Lupus (from Mono's Team) who was kind enough to graciously rewrite the code to let G-WAN better use the Mono runtime.